# Do I always need a static IP to access my front-end on a custom domain in GKE?

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a website (front-end + backend) published on my own GKE cluster. The current configuration relies on one static IP allocated in GCP + one GCE Ingress instance to open the website to internet traffic. It works.

Is there a way to not use a static IP and rely on "ghs.googlehosted.com." ? I don't mind having a fixed static IP. I've tried to set up the DNS as GCP advises on https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains?project=YOURPROJECTID but it doesn't work. Looking at the service logs my FE can communicate internally to my BE. It is just the Ingress + LB configuration that doesn't let the `googlehosted.com` infra know my website is waiting for traffic and all requests should be sent there. Does such a configuration even exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take each piece of the architecture:

- You have your cluster with your services
- You want to expose the services. You create a load balancer
- The load balancer is created with an IP address

So, at the end, you only have an IP, there is no other way to expose a service with GKE. You have to use a Load Balancer, and the load balancer expose an IP.

*Other cloud providers, like AWS, expose a subdomain and not an IP when you create a load balancer, and thus you aren't linked to an IP. It's not the case of GCP, at least for GKE*

Comment: True. At the end there will be an IP. 
That IP however can change however `googlehosted.com` environment wants and I don't have to be worried about it. I already pointed at DNS level the A/AAAA/CNAME record to GoogleHosted, the URL mapping to services is explicitly given to GKE via the Ingress config, the LB created on the back of my config lives outside my cluster and it is visible in App Engine. My question is if I need to **manually** handle the IP address assigned to my LB at DNS level or having already pointed towards `googlehosted.com` it can be handle by GAE. How does it work?

Comment: What is googlehosted.com? It's a HTTPS global loadbalancer, with an anycast IP. This IP is registered in the Google DNS with the name googlehosted.com. To have access to this Google Load Balancer, you need to interact with it. GAE, but also Cloud Run and Cloud Functions do this. GKE and your own Load Balancer not. So you can't use this platform with GKE.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks for clarifying it. I thought for a second Google was visionary and did make some magic behind the scene to allow my Load Balancer to interact with the global LB. In the same way creating an Ingress object in my GKE cluster, creates a LB outside my cluster (naturally), i thought the final hook towards the global LB was a matter of config I wasn't able to dig out. Cheers.

Comment: Your feature request makes sense. Don't hesitate to share it with Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/